# dynamically update elements of array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to update elements into an array from an $.each loop but it loads them incorrectly into the array. it puts all users into one element, all dates into one element and so on 
Here is the code:

```
    var array = [{
      user: "",
      user_id: "",
      date: "",
      profile_img: "",
      text: "",
      contentString: "",
      url: "",
      location: ""
    }];
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23euronews&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&callback=?",

    function (data) {
      $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
        var user = item.from_user;
        var user_id = item.from_user_id;
        var date = item.created_at;
        var profile_img = item.profile_image_url;
        var text = item.text;
        var contentString = text;
        var url = (item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '');
       console.log(i);
       array.user=user;
       array.user_id=user_id;
       array.date=date;
       array.profile_img=profile_img;
       array.text=text;
       array.contentString=contentString;
       array.url=url;

      });
      console.log(array);
       });
```

what shall i do to fix this ?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in`-loops to enumerate arrays - iterate them with traditional for-loops!

Comment: @Bergi good point but in this case there's no need for a loop at all; he's already using `$.each()` to iterate.

Comment: @anjelos Note that the `getJSON` call is asynchronous: `array` won't necessarily be defined in `console.log(array);`.

Comment: @arxanas it's hard to tell but that function is the callback to the `$.getJSON()` call.

Comment: @Pointy: He's iterating `data.results` with `$.each`, but `array` with the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put the update code in that `for ... in` loop. The "i" value is passed into your function. There's no need for the `for` loop.

So just get rid of that loop around the `array[i]` assignments.

Also, the assignments are wrong:

```
 array[i].user = user;
 array[i].user_id = user_id;
```

etc.

Comment: @anjelos what's not working? If you don't describe exactly what's going wrong, how can I help?

Comment: i think is putting only one row of results inside the array

Comment: Did you get rid of the `for` loop?  Have you tried using `console.log()` to report the value of `i` in the callback function?

Comment: yes i removed the for loop and i just tried reporting the value of i and it prints from 0 to 4

Comment: it puts only the last element of the callback's result

Comment: @anjelos perhaps you could edit the question and show your updated code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15470/discussion-between-anjelos-and-pointy)

Comment: @anjelos you left out the `[i]` - should be `array[i].user = user;` etc

Comment: it gives me array[i] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to add users to the `array`. Use the [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method and an object literal, instead of overwriting properties on all objects that already exists in the array:

```
$.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
    array.push( {
        user: item.from_user,
        user_id: item.from_user_id,
        date: item.created_at,
        profile_img: item.profile_image_url,
        text: item.text,
        contentString: text,
        url: item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : ''
    } );
});
console.log(array);
```

To update alreadythe array by overwriting existing items, you might want to use

```
   array[i] = {…};
```

Comment: Well if the returned array items are intended to *update*  `array`, then this wouldn't really work, but if not then this is fine.